# Web development (Spring MVC), slow updates to browser

Tags: javascript, spring, tomcat, webserver, web-deployment

I'm developing a spring MVC application. Spring version 3.1. The IDE i'm using is Eclipse (SpringSource) and browser is Chrome. I think it is a tomcat server.

When I saving the Java files they are loaded to the server, it takes some time to load buts it's OK and i see clearly when it's done.

But the thing that annoys me alot is that I don't see when the JavaScript, JSP and CSS files are being updated. Sometimes it's updating fast and sometimes it feels like ages.

Can I somehow see when these files are being updated or can I force the browser to update them?

Thanks.

Comment: Clear the browser cache.

Comment: I have turned off the browser cache but it don't seems to make any difference.

Comment: Hmm well I don't know what it takes to get Tomcat to update itself short of restarting the process.  (I develop with Jetty for that very reason - it also needs restart, but it's much faster to start than Tomcat.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed this!

In Eclipse I doubleclicked my server in the Servers window.

Then in the overview window that pops up I selected the "Enable JMX-based reloading" tick box.

It defines patterns for files that should be copied to deployed application without triggering a reload. So I just made sure I had all files needed there in the list. (*.css, *.js, *.jsp)

Now it updates fast as hell.