# Spring, sts recompile project on every source change

Tags: spring, maven, build, webdeploy, recompile

I've started to learn spring framework. Earlier I've used play framework.

Generally, spring is more powerful for me, but one thing bothers me: recompile time.

After changing one single line of code I have to click so many times F5 button on the web page of the project to make spring recompile source.

Is there any way to make it recompile on every change of source I made?

Please give me some of your suggestions.
I am using:

- Spring 4
- Spring Tool Suite
- Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.0

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you using tc Server to deploy your project?

Comment: I use defult one. The server I choose in sts is: **Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.0**

Comment: If you open the overview window, you could find a "Publishing" section, when you could configure if you want your publish automatic when resources change or after the build is completed.

Comment: Ok. Found. Changed. Checking...

Comment: This option make it compile more often, but not every time the sources change. I have to press few times refresh button in browser window. Is there any other solution for that?

Comment: Check also the "Auto Reload" option of your web module (make it disabled).

Comment: What do You mean by "Auto Reload"?

Comment: If you were looking at the Overview tab (where you found the publishing section), the other tab name is Modules, there you could find the option of "Auto Reload" for your published web modules.

Comment: Found. Changed. Checking... By the way, In overview tab I have section:  **Application Reload Behavior** and options: **Enable Java Agent-based reloading (experimental)** and **Enable JMX-based reloading**. Non of this is checked. Can it be somehow useful?

Comment: Disable "Auto Reload" and you could take a chance with "Enable Java Agent-based reloading" enabled.

Comment: Ok. It also helped. Thanks You for help. Thanks also to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587262/web-development-spring-mvc-slow-updates-to-browser. Now it is much faster :D

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is a bit old but just stumbled across it.
Spring Boot DevTools will be the best solution to your problem. To include devtools support, simply add the module dependency to your build

**Maven**

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

By default, any entry on the classpath that points to a folder will be monitored for changes. Note that certain resources such as static assets and view templates do not need to restart the application.

Please refer this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) for more details.
We are using the same in our projects. You will just have to add the dependency, and you are good.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18766942)

Comment: @MatteoBaldi Thank you for your comment, I agree and it is a great tip. Will edit this answer, and keep this in mind for future answers. Cheers!